# Predict a future date based on an average

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a formula that will help me predict a future date based on an average time per day.

For example, I have a range of dates [1/12/2022, 5/12/2022, 15/12/2022], and each date has an amount of hours spent on that day [4, 2, 12]. At the moment I have a formula which will work out the average p/day by dividing the total by the start and current date.

What I want is to then predict the date based on this average hours (say 4 p/day) I will reach a goal of 2000.

An example sheet would look like this -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If below scenario is your input data then the following formula may help.

```
=C2+ROUNDUP(B2/A2,0)
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't working in my use case. I've tried adding in my range of dates, then the goal, and current total which is the hours from the range of dates. I think I asked my question wrong so will go back to edit this.

Comment: Share a sample workbook and show your input then desired output.

Comment: Added to original question